# Error in pulling data from RPD -OBIEE 11g

Tags: obiee

I created 2 hierarchies in RPD:

- 1.) Time-Qtr
- 2.) Time-Month

When I tried pulling it out from **OBI 11g** , it returned the following error:

> "Type Error:Unable to get property 'getAllLevelInfos' of undefined or null reference".

What can be done to rectify this errror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your dimensional hierarchies are messed up. They must be constructed on either separate logical dimension tables in order to end on different leaf levels or on one logical dimension table id they are alternate hierarchies inside one dimensional hierarchy this ending on the same leaf level.